# Errors when using Matlab mex

Tags: matlab, fortran, intel, mex, intel-oneapi

I am using Matlab 2023a to call Fortran source file using mex. I use the following compiler for Fortran language compilation:

> Intel oneAPI 2023 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.

The code I used to compile is

> mex ero_dep_fortran.f90 -output ero_dep_fortran

However, I got the following erros:

> Error using mex
> C:\Users\40967\Desktop\Paper bank collapse and meander migration\Draft-version2\Code\ero_dep_fortran.lib �Ͷ���
> C:\Users\40967\Desktop\Paper bank collapse and meander migration\Draft-version2\Code\ero_dep_fortran.exp
> ero_dep_fortran.obj : error LNK2019: �޷��������ⲿ���� NEW_EPOINTS_ASSIGNMENT���÷����ں��� MEXFUNCTION �б�����
> ero_dep_fortran.obj : error LNK2019: �޷��������ⲿ���� omp_get_wtime���÷����ں��� BANK_EROSION_CALCULATION_ENTRY �б�����
> C:\Users\40967\Desktop\Paper bank collapse and meander migration\�޸ĺ����\Draft-version2\Code\ero_dep_fortran.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 2���޷��������ⲿ����

A lot of messy code in the error. I found the main problem maybe

> ero_dep_fortran.obj : error LNK2019

but I do not know how to slove it...This code can be run in other computers with lower version of Matlab and Intel Parallel Studio XE, Microsoft Visual Studio.

Any suggestion is grateful....

Comment: All the relevant text in the error message is gone. Are you using a localized version of MATLAB that translates error messages to some non-Roman alfabet? Maybe you can translate the error message text for us?

Comment: Did you `mex -setup Fortran`? You might also want to rename that directory so it has no spaces in the name; might not be an issue, but sometimes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice you are using a .f90 free format source file. Have you edited the MATLAB supplied compile file to get rid of the silly `/fixed` option on the `$COMPFLAGS` line yet? This forces the compiler to treat your file as a fixed format file which you don't want. Just delete that option from that file.

E.g., On a PC you can check in the `matlabroot\bin\win64\mexopts` directory for an XML file that corresponds to your compiler. Then look for a line that resembles this:

```
 COMPFLAGS="/nologo /fpp /Qprec /fixed /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc $INCLUDE  $COMPDEFINES"
```

Delete the `/fixed` option so that the line looks like this instead:

```
 COMPFLAGS="/nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc $INCLUDE  $COMPDEFINES"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do delect the /fixed option. I think the code is well compiling but fails to link....

Comment: The problem is sloved and is due to that I have several subroutines in the code. I need to compile (in separate f90 file) these subroutines first.